# How can I check for specific values of varchar in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm creating a database in sqlite for a project and I struggle with the part in which I have to create the table with an attribute lets call it ex1 .
The values for ex1 should be a string which has t or T at the end and the other chars build a number in interval from 1 to 30.
So I know how to check if the last char is t or T but I don't know how can I check for the first chars if they build a number from 1 to 30.

It should be something like this for the last character:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename( ex1 VARCHAR NOT NULL CHECK ( ex1 LIKE '%t'));
```

Comment: @glibdud I don't understand what you are trying to say .

Comment: That was a response to a previous deleted comment.

Comment: @glibdud Why did u delete your answer ? It was good but I have one more question . Can you add it again ?

Comment: I realized it had a big problem; I've been trying to find a solution, but I'm coming up blank. If I can't find a solution soon, I'll bring it back with a disclaimer.

Comment: @glibdud What problem did you find ? I tested it with string like '01T' and it was saved in the table , but I want to be only numbers from 1 to 30 without 0 in front of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought was to combine CAST and SUBSTR to check the value of all but the last character in the string:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename( ex1 VARCHAR NOT NULL 
    CHECK ( ex1 LIKE '%t') 
    CHECK ( CAST(SUBSTR(ex1, 1, LENGTH(ex1)-1) AS INT) BETWEEN 1 AND 30 )
);
```

Unfortunately, due to the very permissive way that CAST casts strings to integers (simply ignoring anything after the first non-digit), that will also match a lot of undesirables like `'4.5t'` or even `'23qwerty45t'`.

A messier but more accurate approach, since we're talking about only one or two digits, would be to separately check the one-digit and two-digit cases:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename( ex1 VARCHAR NOT NULL 
    CHECK ( ex1 LIKE '%t') 
    CHECK ( 
            (
              (LENGTH(ex1) = 2) 
                AND 
              (CAST(SUBSTR(ex1, 1, 1) AS INT) BETWEEN 1 AND 9)
            )
              OR
            (
              (LENGTH(ex1) = 3) 
                AND 
              (CAST(SUBSTR(ex1, 1, 2) AS INT) BETWEEN 10 AND 30)
            )
          )
);
```

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO tablename VALUES('1t');
sqlite> INSERT INTO tablename VALUES('30t');
sqlite> INSERT INTO tablename VALUES('31t');
Error: CHECK constraint failed: tablename
sqlite> INSERT INTO tablename VALUES('0t');
Error: CHECK constraint failed: tablename
sqlite> INSERT INTO tablename VALUES('111t');
Error: CHECK constraint failed: tablename
sqlite> INSERT INTO tablename VALUES('tt');
Error: CHECK constraint failed: tablename
sqlite> INSERT INTO tablename VALUES('01t');
Error: CHECK constraint failed: tablename
sqlite> INSERT INTO tablename VALUES('12.5t');
Error: CHECK constraint failed: tablename
sqlite> INSERT INTO tablename VALUES('23qwerty45t');
Error: CHECK constraint failed: tablename
```